# Migrating from Parse.com to Firebase vs Parse Server via Azure?

Tags: azure, parse-platform, firebase

What are your opinions on migrating from Parse.com to Firebase VS Parse Server Hosted By Microsoft Azure? My app is on iOS, Android, and Website and is expecting to receive heavy loads and I was wondering which service would be better for heavy loads, medium loads. In terms of pricing which one is more affordable? What are other pros and cons of each service in comparison to the other? We already migrated to a Parse Server hosted by Azure but wouldn't mind spending another week to switch to Firebase.

Comment: Recommending technologies is off-topic here on Stack Overflow. But if you're considering moving from Parse to Firebase, have a look at the migration guides for [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-ios) and [Android](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/parse-android).

Comment: Also worry Firebase become second parse.com.